# Prestashop custom module tpl getting html encoded

Tags: prestashop, smarty, prestashop-modules

I have created my first custom prestashop(v8) module. For some reason the tpl file is getting html encoded in the website frontend. I inspected the site code and noticed the tpl file content is getting added to the site as follow

```
    <div class="product-additional-info">
    &lt;label for=&quot;custom_instructions&quot;&gt;Custom Instructions&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;textarea id=&quot;custom_instructions&quot; name=&quot;custom_instructions&quot; rows=&quot;4&quot; cols=&quot;50&quot;&gt;&lt;/textarea&gt;

</div>
```

You see how `<label` became `&lt;label` the corresponding tpl file for this looks like this

```
<label for="custom_instructions">{l s='Custom Instructions'}</label>
<textarea id="custom_instructions" name="custom_instructions" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Do you have any ideas or suggestions as to why this is happening? Please check the screenshot of how it looks on the site frontend because of the html encoding.

[image]

Here is the relevant php code as requested

```
<?php
class custominstructions extends Module {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = 'custominstructions';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Sayantan Roy';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Custom Instructions');
        $this->description = $this->l('Add a text box for custom instructions on the product page.');

        // Set the module's bootstrap status to true
        $this->bootstrap = true;
    }

    public function install() {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('displayProductAdditionalInfo') || !$this->registerHook('actionValidateOrder') || !$this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder')) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall() {
        if (!parent::uninstall()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function hookDisplayProductAdditionalInfo($params) {
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'custom_instructions' => $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/custom_instructions.tpl'),
        ));

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/product_additional_info.tpl');
    }

    public function hookActionValidateOrder($params) {
        $order = $params['order'];
        $customInstructions = Tools::getValue('custom_instructions');
        if (!empty($customInstructions)) {
            // Save the custom instructions to the order
            Db::getInstance()->insert('order_message', array(
                'id_order' => (int)$order->id,
                'message' => pSQL($customInstructions),
            ));
        }
    }

    public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($params) {
        $orderId = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order');
        $orderMessages = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'order_message` WHERE `id_order` = '.$orderId);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'orderMessages' => $orderMessages,
        ));

        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/admin/custom_instructions_order.tpl');
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your PHP codes plzz

Comment: @MahdiShad have updated with the PHP code